# Output a string if data not available in Javascript on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this script which is used to append:

```
function append_place(type) {
      var shop_type = type;
      $("#shop_type").append(shop_type);
    }
```

Then in my view.html.erb:

```
<div id="shop_type"></div>
```

where and `type` is the data in my Rails database column.

When `type` has the value `cafe` and the output of the HTML is:

```
<div id="shop_type">Cafe</div>
```

When `type` has no value, the output of the HTML is:

```
<div id="shop_type"></div>
```

I want Javascript to insert `Not available` when `type` has no value:

```
<div id="shop_type">Not available</div>
```

How do I do that? I can't use the normal `if-else` for Rails because the value is delivered via JSON.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var shop_type = !type && type !== 0 ? 'Not available' : type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_%28.7c.7c%29), like this:

```
function append_place(type) {
  var shop_type = type || "Not available";
  $("#shop_type").append(shop_type);
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vvFDY/).

Comment: I like this approach -- although I wonder if it's possible there might be incoming "falsy" data for `type`, like "0", that nevertheless should be shown...

Comment: @Ken - Your solution is using `==`, so it's the same problem :) Test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vvFDY/1/

Comment: Oops, you're right of course! Okay, let's try an even foggier approach.